# upload data to Db through excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba

I have an table PARTY in MYSQL workbench DB , column party_id is primary key,Not Null and unique

```
Party_id  Name     Currency
10080     Person    INR
10081     Party_GP  USD
```

I have the below data in excel which i am going to upload through Macros (here party_id will be null)

```
Party_id   Name         Currency 
           Party_group  GBP
           Company      USD
           Person       INR
```

i have macros code for uploading excel data to MYSQL DB. since here party_id is null , i am unable to insert record into DB. i need macros code to get max (party id) +1 from table PARTY from DB and it should get update  in excel data of party_id  during excel upload.

After upload the result in DB table should be like this

```
Party_id   Name         Currency
10080     Person        INR
10081     Party_GP      USD 
10082      Party_group  GBP
10083      Company      USD
10084      Person       INR
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: I think it's basically a question asking for a query determining the latest Party_id. Explained with too much info ^^

Comment: Would it be possible to change party_id to make it AUTO_INCREMENT and let the database deal with the value by itself?

Comment: PARTY_ID is varchar(20) , auto increment will  not work.
I need to take the max (party_id)+1 from DB table  and assign it to party_id column of the excel during excel upload in macros code. (i think we need to use result set concept) Kindly advise how can we implement this using resultset concept or is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to import csv into MySQL Workbench. I found that it was easier to use an `insert into` statement, which was generated by concatenating the commands around the cells.

In workbench, make sure that your primary key is set to auto-increment, and then I would copy and paste the contents of the concatenated cells(Column D in the example below) directly and run the query.

```
| Party_id | Name        | Currency |                                                                          |
|----------|-------------|----------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          | Party_group | GBP      | ="INSERT INTO `PARTY`,(`Name`, `Currency`) VALUES (`"&B2&"`, `"&C2&"`);" |
|          | Company     | USD      | ="INSERT INTO `PARTY`,(`Name`, `Currency`) VALUES (`"&B3&"`, `"&C3&"`);" |
|          | Person      | INR      | ="INSERT INTO `PARTY`,(`Name`, `Currency`) VALUES (`"&B4&"`, `"&C4&"`);" |
```

Copying Column D would result in pasting the following into workbench:

`INSERT INTO PARTY (Name, Currency) VALUES (Party_group, GBP);
INSERT INTO PARTY (Name, Currency) VALUES (Company, USD);
INSERT INTO PARTY (Name, Currency) VALUES (Person, INR);`

As long as pasty_id is set to auto increment, it should update to the highest value +1